# Save output of cat, pipe, while loop to file

Tags: bash

I want to search in some text for words from list saved as file: `merged.failed`. Then I want to redirect the output of this command to file

```
cat merged.failed | while read f; do grep -io $f /home/some/path/some.txt; done | sort > merged.failed
```

When I do so the merged.failed file becomes empty. However, wihotut `> merged.failed` the correct output prints

Comment: also just `grep -f` and [how to read a file line by line in bash](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: why just ```grep -f```?

Comment: Why not? `grep -iof merged.failed /home/some/path/some.txt` What for to use a while read loop? `grep` already does that.